# Virtual box+Ubuntu:Timed out waiting for device error on boot

Tags: boot, uuid

I have Ubuntu 21.04 installed on Virtual box running on Windows 10 Home.

Everything is fine but after some operations there is an issue when I go to boot. I updated APT package information like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tSjt.png) and installed some tools like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwuI4.png).

After a while, when I reboot there is a long pause and then get into maintenance mode or Ctrl+D to continue. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD9eP.png)

I checked my /etc/fstab out and I can't see anything wrong with it: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUTuN.png)

Also blkid:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH1UJ.png) The UUID of the every partition did not change.

I am new to Linux, many thanks to any advise.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: FYI:  The 21.04 tells you the release you're asking about is the 2021-April release (ie. *year.month* format is used with 2000 added to the year), it had 9 months of supported life, thus April+9 = Jan EOL, so even without seeing the EOL notices you can know it's EOL.  Six months after it's release, the next release (21.10 or 2021-October) came out, giving 3 months to *release-upgrade* systems to that next release before EOL is reached.